# Difference between writing a single prototype on a JavaScript instance and using multiple? Just style?

Tags: javascript, prototype

I'm curious as to the difference between these two ways of writing JavaScript functions using the prototype.  In many JS styleguides the latter is preferred over the former, but I find the latter to be somewhat redundant due to the DRY principle.  Is it just a style issue?  Is one version faster than the other?  Is it something obvious that I'm missing?:

**Keep it DRY?**

```
var Klass = function() {}

Klass.prototype = {
   propertyA: 20,
   propertyB: "hey there",
   methodA: function() {},
   methodB: function() {},
}
```

**Commonly recommended in style-guides:**

```
var Klass = function() {}

Klass.prototype.propertyA = 20;
Klass.prototype.propertyB = "hey there";
Klass.prototype.methodA = function() {};
Klass.prototype.methodB = function() {};
```

Any help in clarifying this would be appreciated!  Thanks --

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The only difference is that the first method replaces the prototype instead of adding to it. If you do it right after assigning the function to the variable, there is no practical difference.

If you use a regular function instead of assigning a function expression to a variable, i.e.:

```
function Klass() {}
```

then there is also the difference that the second method can be used both before and after the declaration of the function, e.g.:

```
Klass.prototype.propertyA = 20;
Klass.prototype.methodA = function() {};

function Klass() {}

Klass.prototype.methodB = function() {};
Klass.prototype.propertyB = "hey there";
```

If you replace the prototype object, you can only to that before *or* after the declaration, so the prototype methods are still in one place.

Answer (score 3):

The first example replaces `prototype` completely with the contents of the object; the second sets individual properties without clobbering the existing data.

You could make the first example work like the second by using some version of `extend` to incorporate that object into the prototype.